# Is there a way to batch multiply a mxn matrix(1) with a pxn matrix(2) where each row of matrix(2) is a scalar?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix(weights) of weights as follows

```
A           B           C           D           E
0.416616274 0.007893688 0.074517004 0.164169555 0.336803478
0.165291635 0.205668613 0.085747923 0.278888074 0.264403755
0.308129534 0.284158392 0.292223348 0.001855199 0.113633527
0.090124092 0.404455217 0.120245226 3.84E-01    0.001496657
0.093981405 0.295247335 0.174392231 0.337238495 0.099140533
0.080119669 0.43934981  0.215148622 0.010537966 0.254843933
0.315502416 0.082623702 0.076406749 0.196668283 0.32879885
```

I have another matrix(daily) as follows:

[image]

Basically, the code I have written is as follows:

```
def f(x):
    if x < 0:
        return abs(x)
    else:
        return x

for i in range(10000):
    weights = np.random.random(num_assets)
    weights /= np.sum(weights)
    #multiply matrix daily by weights, sum all columns and get the min value
    dd = np.multiply(weights, daily).sum(axis=1, skipna = True).min()
    dd = f(dd)
    dd1.append(dd) #append results to empty list
```

I am trying to vectorize this operation rather having to loop through the function thousands of times.  I already have a table(dataframe) of random weights with each row representing the array of weights in the code above.  The code above works but it takes a rather long time to process.  Is there a way to use matrix math to solve this?  I have lookked at np.einsum but I dont understand it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if I get the question right but if you want to multiply the first matrix `[A] (5 x 7)` with `[B] (5 X m)` and then sum each column:

First define your matrix with:

```
weights = np.matrix(np.random.rand(5,7))
daily = np.matrix([ ])
```

then be sure of the shape of each matrix to multiply them (the number of columns of the left matrix must be equal to the number of rows of the right matrix). In this case we need to transpose the rigth matrix (daily):

```
daily = np.transpose(daily)
```

using `np.dot()` multiply the two matrix:

```
matrix_result = np.dot(weights, daily)
```

and finaly to sum each column multiply the matrix_result with a vertical vector of ones

```
v_ones = np.ones(( ))
sums_results = np.dot(matrix_result, v_ones)
```

and thats it, hope I respond your question.